# Haskell: Define Show function for a user defined type, which is defined by "type" key word

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have the type StrInt defined as below

```
type StrInt = (String, Int)

toStrInt:: Str -> Int -> StrInt
toStrInt str int = (str, int)
```

I want the Show function to work as below:
Input: `show (toStrInt "Hello", 123)`
Output: `"Hello123"`

I have tried to define show as below:

```
instance Show StrInt where
    show (str, int) = (show str) ++ (show int)
```

But that gives me error:

```
    Illegal instance declaration for ‘Show StrInt’
      (All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)
       where T is not a synonym.
       Use TypeSynonymInstances if you want to disable this.)
    In the instance declaration for ‘Show StrInt’
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Well, have you tried to use `TypeSynonymInstances` as the error message suggests?

Comment: Although, even if you enable synonym instances, this instance would still be overlapping with the standard one for tuples. Why do you need `show` to work this way?

Comment: @Fyodor Thank you for replying. No I haven't tried ```TypeSynonymInstances```. I have edited my question, please have a look at it. The reason for I wanting show to work this way is that the ''String" and "Int" type in the question is actually some other data type that I have defined using the "data" keyword, say "TypeA" and "TypeB". I want to have a new data type that contains an instance of "TypeA" and "TypeB", and being able to print it out as the string concatication of show TypeA and TypeB

Comment: Consider using a `newtype` wrapper instead.

Comment: Haskell koan: `type` does not declare a user-defined type.

Comment: You haven't define a new type; you've only given a new name to an existing type, one that *already* has a `Show` instance.

Comment: `type` is a *synonym*, and it already has an instance for `Show`, so that will not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do is 1. not a good idea to start with, 2. conflicts with the already-existing `Show` instance and is therefore not possible without `OverlappingInstances` hackery (which is almost never a good idea), and 3. the error message you're getting is *not* related to these problems; other class-instances with the same message may be perfectly fine but of course require the extension that GHC asks about.

1. The `Show` class is *not* for generating arbitrary string output in whatever format you feel looks nice right now. That's the purpose of *pretty-printing*. `Show` instead is supposed to yield *syntactically valid Haskell*, like the standard instance does:

   ```
   Prelude> putStrLn $ show (("Hello,"++" World!", 7+3) :: (String,Int))
   ("Hello, World!",10)
   Prelude> ("Hello, World!",10) -- pasted back the previous output
   ("Hello, World!",10)
   ```

   If you write any `Show` instance yourself, it should also have this property.
2. Again because `(String, Int)` already *has* a `Show` instance, albeit just one arising from more generic instances namely

   ```
   instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (a,b)
   instance Show a => Show [a]
   instance Show Int
   ```

   declaring a new instance for the same type results in a conflict. Technically speaking this could be circumvented by using an `{-# OVERLAPPING #-}` pragma, but I would strongly advise against this because doing that kind of thing can lead to very confusing behaviour down the line when instance resolution inexplicably changes based on how the types are presented.

   Instead, when you really have a good reason to give two different instances to a type containing given data, the right thing to do is generally to make it a *separate* type (so it's clear that there will be different behaviour) which just happens to have the same components.

   ```
   data StrInt' = StrInt String Int
   instance Show StrInt' where
     ...
   ```

   That actually compiles without any further issues or need for extensions. (Alternatively you can also use `newtype StrInt = StrInt (String, Int)`, but that doesn't really buy you anything and just means you can't bring in record labels.)
3. Instances of the form `instance ClassName TypeSynonym` *are* possible too, and can sometimes make sense, but as GHC already informed you they require the `TypeSynonymInstances` extension or one that supersedes it. In fact `TypeSynonymInstances` is not enough if the synonym points to a composite type like a tuple, in that case you need `FlexibleInstances` (which includes `TypeSynonymInstances`), an extension I enable all of the time.

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
   class C
   type StrInt = (String, Int)
   instance C StrInt
   ```

Comment: Beyond “don’t use `Show` for pretty-printing”, I recommend that people *do* use `Pretty` from [`prettyprinter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter).